# JSF: JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component j_idt72

Tags: jsf

I was working on a managed bean and I used `ConfigurableNavigationHandler` to handle a case with implicit redirection. The view ID is valid, and the first time the this redirection method is called, the user is redirected to the correct page and the user logs in. But if the method is called again and the redirected view is not closed, it will report this error and the user be directed to some unwanted views. How do I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some code for what you've already tried?